# What do the planets in our solar system smell like?

Tags: planets, solar-system, biology, chemical-compounds

For example, if Jupiter is mostly hydrogen and and helium, but has ammonia clouds, does that mean it smells like a cat's litterbox?

Does Mars smell like iron?

Asking in order to give kids a more "tangible" understanding of what various planets are made of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Does something you can't survive inhaling even have a smell? ;)

Comment: @JohnRennie If the question is not in topic, then it should be migrated, not closed.

Comment: *to give kids a more "tangible" understanding of what various planets are made of* One of the first things you should tell them is that smelling and inhaling gases like these is a very bad idea.  And at the temperatures and pressures they're at you would not live long enough to worry about the smell.

Comment: @Pere: If you're going to recommend migration, please specify *where* you think it would be a better fit. I can only presume you mean [astronomy.se], but not entirely sure.

Comment: @KyleKanos Planets and their atmospheres are seen as on topic both on astronomy and space exploration sites - oddly overlapping. I'd say AstronomySE is a better fit, but that might be debatable.

Comment: @StephenG I'm trying to solve the problem that if you rattle off factoids to elementary or preschool kids like "Jupiter is mostly hydrogen, helium and methane" they can parrot it back but they won't really "get" what those things are. If you can say it's made of what goes in balloons and what smells like farts, they get an impression that sticks better :) Of course if some gas vapors would literally burn your lungs, that's also a tangible concept...

Comment: To teach them what the facts mean you need to show them the effect of those high or low temperatures and pressures.  The smell would tell them nothing useful and does not relate any useful science concept to them.  E.g. what happens meat in an oven, or a fridge.  My experience is that kids respond to gory details (OK, up to a point) - tell them an astronaut will be squished on Venus and you get their attention - that kind of thing.

Comment: @StephenG Smell is only one aspect, but it was intended to explain one part of what the planets are made of. The overall lesson also covers pressure, heat, etc. The problem is I don't know how to ask these questions here without getting them marked on hold or off topic--I tried separating the questions but they're still marked as too broad.

Comment: The overall, seriously too broad questions are "if I gave a child a solar system to play with, what would it feel like? How would it react to different actions? What would it be like to be at the surface?" The last question is the easiest one, so that's covered. The other questions are what I could use expert help on.

Comment: If you could smell it, the Jovian moon Io would smell like rotting eggs ;)